# MantisBT: Verification Message was not sent in my gmail

Tags: php, mantis

Webserver: Localhost (WAMP)

Error display in Signing Up:

> SYSTEM WARNING: 'stream_socket_enable_crypto() [streams.crypto]: this
>   stream does not support SSL/crypto' in
>   'C:\wamp\www\bugtracker\library\phpmailer\class.smtp.php' line 249

Codes in **CONFIG_INC.php**

```
<?php
$g_hostname = 'localhost';
$g_db_type = 'mysql';
$g_database_name = 'bugtracker';
$g_db_username = 'root';
$g_db_password = '';

$g_allow_signup    = ON;  //allows the users to sign up for a new account
$g_enable_email_notification = ON; //enables the email messages
$g_phpMailer_method = PHPMAILER_METHOD_SMTP; // this is most important
$g_smtp_host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$g_smtp_connection_mode = 'tls';
$g_smtp_port = 587;
$g_smtp_username = 'myemail@gmail.com'; //replace it with your gmail address
$g_smtp_password = 'mypassword'; //replace it with your gmail password
$g_administrator_email = 'adminaccount@example.com'; //this will be your administrator email address
```

I also tried changing:

```
$g_smtp_connection_mode = 'ssl';
$g_smtp_port = 465;
```

What do I need to add?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do the following:

1. Click WAMP then
2. Apache >> Apache modules >>ssl_module
3. PHP >> Php extensions >> php_openssl

Work Great. Thanks

*https://www.mantisbt.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=15398&sid=fed5ee9fd9b578d093f4fb7b80085f82&start=15*